# Change the value of unconfigurable properties in JavascriptCore (redefining un-configurable property from C/Obj-C APIs)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit

I am developing a thin client application using the Objectice-C WebKit API under OSX, and there are few cases where it is desirable to override some properties of the `window` object, like `window.localStorage` (to provide my own localStorage implementation, since OSX' is not persistent), `window.parent` (so that some child frame behave like a top level iframe), or some others.

However these properties are marked as "unconfigurable", and I can't override them even from the C/Obj-C APIs.

Is there a way to make these properties configurable again ? Or just to override them from the C/C++/Objc-C side ?

Comment: I have/had a similar question...unfortunately no one knows/has seen this